# c++ parse file and read binary

Tags: c++, parsing, binary, stdio

I want to save email accounts and passwords, which I will have previously encrypted with an algorithm. They need to be saved and read as binaries, with fwite and fread. What I want, is to be able to know if it's a pass or an email account, saving it between < e > < e > and < u > < u >

For example:

```
<e> !"§(!"$)Asdn12§(!"§UASD <e>
<u> !"§()!="§ksd!"§KM!"§lkm12 <u>
<e> !"§KMK!M"§asd9i1ikm23ß0 <e>
<u> l,1ö2l3!"§)IQASD=K!"E <u>
```

how do you suggest should I read the file as binary but be also able to parse it.

Those emails and passes are read by another prog which performs some tasks with them.

Comment: Are usernames and passwords always paired?

Comment: Why <p> and <u>?  Are you thinking of xml?

Comment: Off topic: [please securely hash your passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) instead of encrypting them.

Comment: yes they are always paired, no xml just a way to know it's a pass or usename

Comment: read your file in to `vector<unsigned char>` then search for <p> and <u>, as long as your encryption never produces those tokens you will be fine.

Comment: On topic: If you're saving the data as binary, then typically you would define a file format. For example, the first few bytes can specify how many username/password pairs you have, then you can have a header consisting of a few bytes that specifies how long the username and password is, then have the actual username and passwords follow it. Repeat for each pair. You may save a hash of the data to check for integrity.

Comment: @In Silico no I can'T hash them they read in a file and feeded to another program which in certain time intervals performs some tasks with them, not actually usernames but email accounts and their passwords

Comment: In general, you're doing a lot wrong.

Comment: @In silico what do you mean by integrity?

Comment: @Tasos Papanikolaou: A hash can be used to detect (accidental) corruption of the file. This may be important in binary files where the position of bytes may be significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If usernames and passwords are always paired I suggest you store the length (in number of bytes) before each username and before each password.  This way you can read the length (say a 4 byte integer) and know how long the next username / password record will be.  You can then repeat this without worrying about searching for tags that could occur within a username or password.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Writing your own crypto is a general no-no.

If you need to save usernames and passwords for authentication or logging into services, I recommend saving it normally but relying on the OS's file permissions to keep it safe (this is standard Unix practice, as if the OS is compromised you've lost anyway).

If you do need publicly-readable but encrypted passwords, use a freely-available encryption library and put the decryption key right into the source code (and compiled binary). This is as secure as you can be, since an attacker can just read the memory after decryption anyway.

I strongly recommend thinking about why you need encryption, and who you're trying to hide the information from.